# segmentation fault inside on loop

Tags: c, pointers

I'm C# man, new in C language working with points first time.

I have this function that works with `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` at future:

```
char ** split(char * delimiter, char * input) {

        int i = 0;
        int size = sizeof(char *);
        char ** tokens;
        char * token;
        char * state; 
        tokens = (char **) malloc(size);

        if(tokens == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation failed.");
            return;
        }

        for(token = strtok_r(input, delimiter, &state); 
             token != NULL;
             token =  strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &state),
             i++, size *= i) {

             tokens = (char **) realloc(tokens, size);

             if(tokens == NULL) {
                printf("Realloc failed.");
                return;
             }

             tokens[i] = state;
        }

        return tokens;
}
```

when I call:

```
char * IPNumber = "127.0.01";
char * delimiter = "."; 
char ** parts = split(delimiter, IPNumber);
```

it gives `segmentation fault`.

I'm looking for an explanation how to get(calculate) the size value to be used in the second argument of `realloc()` function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: How are you calling the function ?

Comment: IanGilham,cnicutar see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete rewrite**.  There are some issues with the original code as posted.

- The reallocation size computation is incorrect.
- The passing of a string constant to strtok_r is not valid.  It modifies the first argument, so that could result in an access violation when passed the string literal.
- The assignment of the token into the result array starts at position 1 instead of 0.
- The assignment uses the state variable instead of the token (probably not at all the desired result and probably undefined behavior).
- There is no way for the caller to know how many tokens are in the returned array.
- A failed call to realloc does not free the original pointer, so it would leak.

So rather than attempt to describe the changes, I'll follow the same pattern as others and show what might be a cleaner implementation with a single allocation based on the max possible number of tokens.

```
char ** split(char * delimiter, char * input) {
    int size;
    int maxsize;
    char ** tokens;
    char * token;
    char * state;

    // compute max possible tokens, which is half the input length.
    // Add 1 for the case of odd strlen result and another +1 for
    // a NULL entry on the end
    maxsize = strlen( input ) / 2 + 2;
    tokens = (char**)malloc( maxsize * sizeof( char*) );
    if(tokens == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation failed.");
        return NULL;
    }

    size = 0;
    for(token = strtok_r(input, delimiter, &state);
         token != NULL;
         token =  strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &state) ) {

         tokens[size++] = token;
    }

    assert( size < maxsize );
    // Put a NULL in the last entry so the caller knows how many entries
    // otherwise some integer value would need to be returned as an output
    // parameter.
    tokens[size] = NULL;

    // NOTE: could use realloc from maxsize down to size if desired

    return tokens;
}
```

Usage might look like the following.  Note the use of `strdup` to avoid passing the string constant to the function:

```
char * IPNumber = strdup( "127.0.01" );
char * delimiter = ".";
char ** parts = split(delimiter, IPNumber);
int i;

if ( parts ) {
   for ( i = 0; parts[i] != NULL; i++ )
      printf( "%s\n", parts[i] );

   free( parts );
   }

free( IPNumber );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to increment `i++` out of loop,before of assignment `tokens[i] = token;` and calculate it as you say. But it solved not my problem, I get same error.

Comment: @TheMask:  I probably wasn't clear on moving the increment out of the loop.  It needs to be at the bottom of the loop in that case.  If you increment it prior to the assignment, it will skip the first position in the array and still overwrite memory.  I'll edit and try to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The sizes of your malloc/calloc are wrong (you multiply by the intended count, which makes the array grow by `count!`)

On the first item: i=0, size=sizeof(char*);
On the second item i=1, size=sizeof(char) /*that is too small for two elements */

```
char ** split(char * delimiter, char * input) {

        unsigned size , used;
        char ** array = NULL;
        char * token;
        char * state; 

        size = used = 0;
        for(token=strtok_r(input, delimiter, &state); token; token=strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &state) ) {

             if (used+1 >= size) {
                        size = size ? 2*size: 4;
                        array = realloc(array, size * sizeof *array);

                        if (!array) { printf("Realloc failed."); return NULL ; /*leak here*/ }
             }

             array[used++] = state;
        }
        /* NOTE: need a way to communicate the number of elements back to the caller */
        if (array) array[used] = NULL;

        return array;
}
```

UPDATE: here is a test driver

```
int main(void)
{
char stuff[] = "this is the stuff";
char **ppp;
unsigned idx;

ppp = split( " " , stuff);
for (idx = 0; ppp && ppp[idx]; idx++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%u: %s\n", idx, ppp[idx] );
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works (that is: it does not crash). It skips the first element, and adds an extra element that points to an empty string at the end. But it does not crash. BTW: the way you call it, *input points to a read-only string "127.0.0.1". That will not work, strtok() wants writable strings.

Comment: what is your platform and compiler? it does not worked for me, on: ubuntu 10.4, gcc  4.4.3.

Comment: Works perfectly here (ubuntu 10.x) but gives the wrong results here. I'' add a main(){} driver.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I guessed what you intended was to return an array of strings:

## include

```
char ** split(char * delimiter, char * input) {
        int i;
        char ** tokens;
        char * token;
        char * state;

        tokens = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (2));

        if(tokens == NULL) {
            printf("Allocation failed.");
            return NULL;
        }

        tokens[0]=(char *)1; /* one element populated */
        tokens[1]=NULL; /* no tokens */

        for(i=1, token = strtok_r(input, delimiter, &state);
             token != NULL;
             token =  strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &state),
             i++) {

             /* grow array by one element - originally made with 2 */
             {
               char **new =(char **) realloc(tokens, (i+2) * sizeof(char *));

                 if(new == NULL) {
                    printf("Realloc failed.");
                    free(tokens);
                    return NULL;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    tokens = new;
                    tokens[i+1] = NULL;  /* initialize new entry */
                 }
             }

             tokens[i] = token;
             tokens[0] = (char *)i;
        }

        return tokens;
}

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "129.128.0.1";
    char delim[] = ".";
    char **ret;

    ret = split( delim, str );

    printf( "tokens = %d\n", (int)ret[0] );
    printf( "tokens[1] = %s\n", ret[1] );
    printf( "tokens[2] = %s\n", ret[2] );
    printf( "tokens[3] = %s\n", ret[3] );
    printf( "tokens[4] = %s\n", ret[4] );
    printf( "tokens[5] = %s\n", ret[5] );
}
```

1. return explicit values, not garbage.
2. change in realloc function.  You grow the array by one element during each loop.
3. Fix memory leak
4. save the value returned by strtok_r, not its private internal state variable.
5. the array is one larger then it needs to be, so make sure it gets initialized to NULL
6. entry zero of the array is the size, which should not overflow unless you are handling *HUGE* strings

Comment: $ ./strings.exe
tokens = 4
tokens[1] = 129
tokens[2] = 128
tokens[3] = 0
tokens[4] = 1
tokens[5] = (null)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to point out things to fix, but instead just rewrote it as follows:

```
char **split(char *delim, char *input)
{
  char *save;  /* saved state for strtok_r */
  char **tmp,  /* temporary result from realloc (for error handling) */
       **res;  /* result - NULL-terminated array of tokens */
  int i,       /* index of current/last token */ 
      count;   /* number of elements in res (including NULL) */

  /* Allocate first element for res */
  if ( !(res = malloc(sizeof(res[0]))) ) {
    /* return NULL if malloc() fails */
    fprintf(stderr,"split(): malloc() failed\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  /* res[0] = first token, or NULL */
  res[0] = strtok_r(input,delim,&save);

  /* if it was a token, grab the rest.  Last one will be the NULL
   *  returned from strtok_r() */
  if (res[0])
    i = 0;
    count = 1;
    do {
      /* Resize res, for next token */
      /* use a temporary pointer for realloc()'s result, so that
       *  we can check for failure without losing the old pointer */
      if ( tmp = realloc(res, sizeof(res[0]) * ++count) )
        res = tmp;
      else {
        /* if realloc() fails, free res and return NULL */
        free(res);
        fprintf(stderr,"split(): realloc() failed.\n");
        return NULL;
      }
      /* get next token, or NULL */
      res[++i] = strtok_r(NULL,delim,&save);
    } while (res[i]); /* done when last item was NULL */

  return res;
}
```

So the size for realloc is the number of elements needed, multiplied by the size of an element.

The above version of the code returns a NULL-terminated array.  Another approach would be to return the number of array elements somehow (like via an `int *` or `size_t *` argument); but in any case you need a way for the caller to know where the end of the results array is.

Using `strtok_r()` for this also adds another catch:  The original `input` string is *not* left intact.  So you'll need to bear that in mind when using this (or your original) function as well -- either use it when you don't need to preserve the original string, or make a duplicate of the original first.